# How do I use Jolt to flatten a json array of n objects with the key?

Tags: flatten, jolt

I have a fairly straightforward use case, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the shift specification that would make this transpose possible. It's primarily just flattening the tree hierarchy into simple output arrays.

How would a turn this input JSON:

```
{
  "123": [
    {
      "VALUE_ONE": "Y",
      "VALUE_TWO": "12"
    },
    {
      "VALUE_ONE": "N",
      "VALUE_TWO": "2"
    }
  ],
  "456": [
    {
      "VALUE_ONE": "Y",
      "VALUE_TWO": "35"
    }
  ]
}
```

Into this output:

```
[
  {
    "value_one_new_name": "Y",
    "value_two_new_name": "12",
    "key": "123"
  },
  {
    "value_one_new_name": "N",
    "value_two_new_name": "2",
    "key": "123"
  },
  {
    "value_one_new_name": "Y",
    "value_two_new_name": "35",
    "key": "456"
  }
]
```

NOTE that I don't know what the key ("456", "123" .. etc) would be for each object, so the jolt spec needs to be generic enough to convert any keys, only known field names are "VALUE_ONE" and "VALUE_TWO".

Answer (score 1):

This steps will do the trick:

```
    [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "VALUE_ONE": "&2.[&1].value_one_new_name",
          "VALUE_TWO": "&2.[&1].value_two_new_name",
          "$1": "&2.[&1].key"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```